# Bookmarks in chrome for Android unorganized when trying to add

Tags: android, google-chrome

When trying to add a bookmark in chrome v119.xxx for Android v13, the folders and subfolders show up in a total random hierarchy. Any idea what may cause this, and how to fix?

I obviously expect bookmarks to show up in the folder structure I created, which also shows up correctly when using them. But not when adding...